# Reactjs, parent component, state and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, fluxible

I m actually learning reactjs and I m actually developping a little TODO list, wrapped inside of a "parent component" called TODO.

Inside of this parent, I want to get the current state of the TODO from the concerned store, and then pass this state to child component as property.

The problem is that I dont know where to initialize my parent state values.

In fact, I m using ES6 syntax, and so, I dont have getInitialState() function. It's written in the documentation that I should use component constructor to initialize these state values.

The fact is that if I want to initialize the state inside of my constructor, the this.context (Fluxible Context) is undefined actually.

I decided to move the initialization inside of componentDidMount, but it seems to be an anti pattern, and I need another solution. Can you help me ?

Here's my actual code :

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoTable from './TodoTable';
import ListStore from '../stores/ListStore';

class Todo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {listItem:[]};
    this._onStoreChange = this._onStoreChange.bind(this);
  }

  static contextTypes = {
      executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState(this.getStoreState()); // this is what I need to move inside of the constructor
      this.context.getStore(ListStore).addChangeListener(this._onStoreChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.context.getStore(ListStore).removeChangeListener(this._onStoreChange);
  }

  _onStoreChange () {
   this.setState(this.getStoreState());
 }

  getStoreState() {
      return {
          listItem: this.context.getStore(ListStore).getItems() // gives undefined
      }
  }

  add(e){
    this.context.executeAction(function (actionContext, payload, done) {
        actionContext.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'toto', key:new Date().getTime()});
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className='waves-effect waves-light btn' onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        <TodoTable listItems={this.state.listItem}></TodoTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Todo;
```

Comment: I am curious, where did you read that getting or setting a `state` inside a `componentDidMount` method is an _anti-pattern_?

Comment: @TahirAhmed, Here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: hmm but where does it mention `componentDidMount` in that article? I mean what I do in my projects is pretty much what you are doing i.e. using `this.setState(...)` inside a `componentDidMount` function and till now, I thought it was just fine to use that. I am now curious what others think of that as I personally don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Fluxible user you should benefit from [Fluxible addons](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-addons-react):

- [connectToStores](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-addons-react/blob/master/docs/api/connectToStores.md).

The following example will listen to changes in FooStore and BarStore and pass foo and bar as props to the Component when it is instantiated.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{this.props.foo}</li>
                <li>{this.props.bar}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

Component = connectToStores(Component, [FooStore, BarStore], (context, props) => ({
    foo: context.getStore(FooStore).getFoo(),
    bar: context.getStore(BarStore).getBar()
}));

export default Component;
```

Look into [fluxible example](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/todo%2Fcomponents%2FTodoApp.jsx) for more details. Code exсerpt:

```
var connectToStores = require('fluxible-addons-react/connectToStores');
var TodoStore = require('../stores/TodoStore');
...

TodoApp = connectToStores(TodoApp, [TodoStore], function (context, props) {
    return {
        items: context.getStore(TodoStore).getAll()
    };
});
```

As a result you wouldn't need to call setState, all store data will be in component's props.

Comment: I was wondering if there is something possible to decouple fluxible from our react components ? Do you think that it's a good idea to create reactjs component, export them, and when importing in another file, we decorate it inside of the other file ? So our reactjs component can be easily exported and decoration is only inside of fluxible projects

Comment: read through this article https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0. You should keep dump components know nothing about fluxible (they operate only with props and own state), only top level smart components will have some logic to integrate with fluxible stores

Comment: So my solution seems to be a good thing, even for parent components no ?

Comment: It will justify the cost only if you are going to reuse root components in other projects where you may use different flux library. IMHO I would not recommend, it creates to much of boilerplate code